# Why can't I read a file when I have group permissions

Tags: linux

I have created a new admin group which I am a member of. I have changed permissions of the file `test_admin.txt` so that it can only be read and written by members of this group: ls -a returns

```
----rw---- 1 joe.bloggs admin     37 Feb  6 16:49 test_admin.txt
```

groups joe.bloggs returns

```
joe.bloggs : linkmed admin
```

I have logged out and back in as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054888/why-cant-i-write-eventhough-i-have-group-permissions but I still receive the same error message

```
test_admin.txt: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are many possibilities but where's the file? Permissions there? Device (could be mounted read-only) / Dir (not even getting there) ?

Comment: @TommiKyntola The file is in my home area where I have user permissions. How do I check if the device is mounted read-only?

Comment: The answer below is correct. You're accessing it as joe.bloggs, right? Then you need to give him some access rights, too. Make it 660, i.e. chmod 660 test_admin.txt or chmod u+rw test_admin.txt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user himself does not have the permission to view the file. The user permissions have precedence over the group permissions. Set the file readable for its owner as well.

Comment: I can now access the file, although the others in the group cannot

Comment: @moadeep: How did you set the permissions? What are the permissions now?

Comment: To set up the group `groupadd -r admin` `usermod -G admin joe.bloggs` `usermod -G jane.bloggs`. To change group ownership of the file `chgrp admin test_admin.txt` `chmod g+rw test_admin.txt`. I then gave myself read write permissions as suggested by yourself `chmod 660 test_admin.txt`

Comment: @moadeep: It should work. Do the other group members have the persmission to get to the directory?

Comment: They should do - everyone has access to the directory `drwxrwxr-x  4 bill.bloggs    all  166 Feb 11 10:00 admin/`

Comment: The user jane.bloggs has to log in again for the group changes to take effect.