# Permissions allowing the deletion of a file

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Given below are the results of `ls -l` calls for a file and its containing (parent) directory. In which of the following cases can the user (student1) delete the file:

a.

```
---------- 1 student1 student1    0 Feb 10 20:47 file1
d-wx------ 2 student1 student1 4096 Feb 10 20:47 directory1
```

b.

```
-rwx------ 1 student1 student1    0 Feb 10 20:47 file1
drw------- 2 student1 student1 4096 Feb 10 20:47 directory1
```

c.

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 student1 student1    0 Feb 10 20:47 file1
dr-x------ 2 student1 student1 4096 Feb 10 20:47 directory1
```

d.

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 student1 student1    0 Feb 10 20:47 file1
dr-xrwx--- 2 student1 student1 4096 Feb 10 20:47 directory1
```

Can anyone explain why the correct answer is (a)? As far as I know when deleting I should look at the permessions on the parent directory, but I can't seem to understand what the difference is between a, b, c and d.

Comment: Can you refine the question?  Do you understand the meaning of `r`, `w`, and `x`?  If so, what difficulty do you have understanding the difference between `-wx`, `rw-`, and `r-x`?

Comment: I understand that it stands for
w-write
r-read
x-execution
But why only in (a) can I delete? what has to happen so that I can delete?

Comment: "As far as I know when deleting I should look at the permissions on the parent directory".  What permissions do you look for in the parent directory to be able to delete things from it?

Comment: Related: [Why can't I read a file when I have group permissions](http://superuser.com/q/549955/150988), and probably a few hundred others.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in all of these cases, the ownership is a mixture of `student1` and `studen1`. I am going to simply assume that this is a typo and the real situation described is that both the directory and the file are owned by the student's user account and corresponding group, which is the same for both.

In most implementations, directories are really a special kind of file (like a block device node or a file system pipe) that hold a list of files (and other directories) that logically exist within it, as well as pointers to itself and its parent directory (the `.` and `..` entries, respectively). Changing the list of files within the directory involves updating this directory-file.

In standard Linux, the owner can always delete their own files. This is a fairly logical extension of the fact that the owner is able to change the permissions of the file, so even if they wouldn't have been able to delete it originally because of the file's permissions, they could trivially give themselves that permission.

However, since deleting a file involves writing to the directory (to remove the reference to the file), the user deleting the file *must have write access to the directory that file resides in.*

Case (a) is the only one of your cases where the user has write access to the directory, and hence the only case in which the user can delete files within that directory.

In case (b) you are unable to descend into the directory (lack of `x` permission) and thus cannot do anything at all with its contents.

In case (c) you lack write permissions on the directory, and thus cannot change the contents of the directory.

Case (d) *could in principle* have worked, but since user permissions override group permissions, which in turn override world permissions (where each more-specific type of permission is applicable to the user performing the action), the lack of write access to the directory for the user takes precedence over the group having write access. Hence deleting fails because of a lack of access rights.

Consider the (somewhat non-obvious) way that regular file permissions (read/write/execute) are mapped onto directories, and what they mean:

- `r` permission on the directory means you can list the files, **because** it allows reading the directory-file
- `w` permission on the directory means you can add, edit and delete *directory entries*, **because** it allows writing to the directory-file
- `x` permission on the directory means you can descend into the directory, allowing you to access a directory entry *given that you know its name*, **because** reasons (and there needed to be some way to express the ability to descend into a directory)

Comment: What about case (b)? `rw`on the directory is not enough to delete the file?

Comment: What about (b) in (b) it also has the write flag on. So why can't you also delete in case (b)?

Comment: @jcbermu No, `rw-` on the directory is not sufficient to descend into the directory, and thus you cannot do anything with it.

Comment: @Asa See my edit.